# Non uniform circular motion, can you find the error?

Tags: derivatives, physics

The vector function and its derivatives for a non uniform circular motion is:

$$ \vec s(t) = r \cdot \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\omega t) \\ \sin(\omega t) \end{bmatrix}, \qquad \omega = \omega(t) $$

$$ \vec v(t) = r \cdot \left({d\omega \over dt} t + \omega\right)
\begin{bmatrix} -\sin(\omega t) \\ \cos(\omega t) \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ \vec a(t) = -r \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
\left({d^2\omega \over dt^2} t + 2{d\omega \over dt}\right) \sin(\omega t) + \left({d\omega \over dt} t + \omega\right)^2 \cos(\omega t)
\\
-\left({d^2\omega \over dt^2} t + 2{d\omega \over dt}\right) \cos(\omega t)
+ \left({d\omega \over dt} t + \omega\right)^2 \sin(\omega t)
\end{bmatrix} $$

**Something weird about $\vec v$**

As $t$ approaches $∞$ and ${d\omega \over dt} \ne 0$, $|\vec v|$ also approaches $∞$.
That's no reason for speed to approach $∞$.

**Consider this**
$$ \omega(t) = {1 \over r}{d\ell(t) \over dt},
\qquad \mathrm{where \ \ell(t) \ is \ the \ circle's \ traveled \ arc \ length \ after \ time \ t
} $$

$${d\ell(t) \over dt} = |\vec v(t)| \quad \mathrm{gives} \quad |\vec v(t)| = r \omega(t) $$

**But** $ |\vec v(t)| = r \cdot \left({d\omega \over dt} t + \omega\right) $ **!!!**

Comment: What do you mean there's no reason? If you have, let's say constant angular acceleration, i.e. $\dot \omega = \epsilon$, then your point can spin as fast as you want, after certain time's past.

Comment: The second derivative is wrong: it misses the term $-r \sin\omega t (d/dt)(\omega't+\omega)$ and similarly for the second component.

Comment: Thanks for noticing error with the derivative.

Comment: To Kaster: I mean speed increases/decreases because of acceleration, not time its self.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions seem to imply that you're under the impression that your quantity $\omega$ is the instantaneous angular velocity. This is not the case, as you can see e.g. from the fact that, as you noted, $|\vec v(t)|=r\omega(t)$ doesn't hold, whereas this holds for the instantaneous angular velocity.

To describe a non-uniform circular motion, use

$$
\vec s(t) = r \cdot \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\phi (t)) \\ \sin(\phi(t)) \end{bmatrix}\;;
$$

then

\begin{align}
\vec v(t) &= r\dot\phi(t) \cdot \begin{bmatrix}-\sin(\phi (t)) \\ \cos(\phi(t)) \end{bmatrix}\\
&=r\omega(t)\cdot \begin{bmatrix}-\sin(\phi (t)) \\ \cos(\phi(t)) \end{bmatrix}\;.
\end{align}

Comment: Now I see it. In my vector function omega was average angular velocity after time t. But considered it to be instantaneous. Thank you.